# Overall approach for building a footfall/age/gender counter using CCTV footage

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-processing, opencv

I would like some advice to validate my approach for building a computer vision system.

#### Design brief:

Using existing CCTV cameras in a retail store, detect the footfall in the shop (count individual visitors) and determine their apparent age and gender.

- System will run on a computer with an Nvidia Jetson Xavier AGX with 32GB RAM.
- Collects data real time.
- The system should ideally be adaptable to other stores with different cameras etc. - it isn't a one-off solution.
- accuracy only needs to be sufficient for aggregate analytics over days/weeks.

#### Constraints:

- I don't have access to test footage from the shop yet - have to build a first attempt without this info.
- The CCTV cameras in the shop aren't too high resolution, and are placed at a high angle on the ceiling. Any detected faces would be small and low resolution and a side-on view.
- The system should be able to deal with people wearing masks.
- The store will have display racks etc. so people might be partially occluded and the system should deal w that.
- Data privacy issues need to be considered.

#### First attempt

I've built a first attempt that processes the footage frame by frame. It uses a person detector and a face detector to get bounding boxes. It uses a centroid tracker assign IDs to each person using the person bounding boxes. It sends the face detections to age and gender caffe models trained on [IMDB faces](https://sefiks.com/2020/09/07/age-and-gender-prediction-with-deep-learning-in-opencv/). The gender and age detection is not accurate at all. Probably because the faces are small in the sample video - like 50x50 pixels. The gender detection is highly biased towards male classifications.

#### New attempt

- I'm figuring that using full-body person attribute detection is more appropriate than face-only age/gender detection for this application? Should I abandon face-based approaches?
- An approach like DeepSORT rather than centroid tracking will probably work better.
- Using YOLOv4 for person detection.
- I need to include some person re-identification since I need to determine the overall time spent in the store. How would you approach this?

I'm experimenting with this library [KaiyangZhou](https://github.com/KaiyangZhou)/**[deep-person-reid](https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid)** for both the person attribute detection (trained with PA-100K) and person re-id (trained with Market-1501).

How would you approach building this project?

This is my first computer vision project so open to seemingly obvious advice.

Comment: This is a very deep question. Look into the Visual Genome for training data. But this is a 10 people 2 years project.